# react native how to open a link in default browser from android and ios without using Linking.openURL

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I have a website, an ios app and android app.

Some deeplinks to the website I catch in the deeplink handling. However some I can't handle in the app so have to redirect the user back to the website. but in doing this I retrigger the deeplinks because for android the intent filter catches it again and in ios the same url is in the site-association so it retriggers the deeplink in the app again, causing an infinite loop.

Can I force opening the default browser without using Linking.openURL(url) ?

Is there perhaps some kind of intent I can send to open a browser?
`Linking.sendIntent(...)`

I have many paths on [www.mydomain.com/foo/bar](http://www.mydomain.com/foo/bar) which I handle in the deeplinking in the app via intent filters for android and site association for ios. but there many paths which I don't handle
e.g. [www.mydomain.com/foo/not-this](http://www.mydomain.com/foo/not-this)  and which i want redirect the user back to the browser.

I have too many paths to hard code them all and they change frequently, only a regex might help but as far as I understand it neither the android intent filters nor the site association file for ios have much in the way of regex handling so it limits you to using a small subset with wildcards etc. so I end up capturing more urls than can be handled in the app.

Comment: could you brief the current deeplink handling functionality of your app here

Comment: @EL173 I have added more context.

Comment: Seems you are using an your own method to handle the deeplinks. If you could migrate to Firebase Dynamic Links #https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links, It will easy to resolve all of your complications plus there are more support on this on as well

Comment: Did you ever solve this? In the same situation and want to send user to web browser when we decide we can't open the link. Using openUrl puts you in an infinite loop. Android App Link capabilities are too basic to filter out all URLs in manifest.